# MATLAB parfor slicing a 3D array

Tags: algorithm, matlab, parfor, sliding-window

I'm trying to speed up my code using `parfor`. The purpose of the code is to slide a 3D square window on a 3D image and for each block of `mxmxm` apply a function.

I wrote this code:

```
function [ o_image ] = SlidingWindow( i_image, i_padSize, i_fun, i_options )
%SLIDINGWINDOW Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

o_image = zeros(size(i_image,1),size(i_image,2),size(i_image,3));
i_image = padarray(i_image,i_padSize,'symmetric');
i_padSize = num2cell(i_padSize);
[m,n,p] = deal(i_padSize{:});
[row,col,depth] = size(i_image);
windowShape = i_options.windowShape;
mask = i_options.mask;
parfor (i = m+1:row-m,i_options.cores)
    temp = i_image(i-m:i+m,:,:);
    for j = n+1:col-n
        for h = p+1:depth-p
            ii = i-m;
            jj = j-n;
            hh = h-p;
            temp = temp(:,j-n:j+n, h-p:h+p);
            o_image(ii,jj,hh) = parfeval(i_fun, temp, windowShape, mask);
        end
    end
end

end
```

I get one warning and one error that I don't understand how to solve.
The warning says:

> the entire array or structure 'i_image' is a broadcast variable.

The error says:

> the PARFOR loop can not run due to the way variable 'o_image' is used.

I don't understand how to fix these two things. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, [`parfeval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html) takes care of running your function on the available number of workers, which is why it doesn't need to be surrounded by `parfor`. Assuming you already have an active [`parpool`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parpool.html), **changing the external `parfor` into `for` eliminates both problems**.

Unfortunately, I can't support my answer with a benchmark or suggest a more fitting solution because your inputs are unknown.

It seems to me that the code can be optimized in other ways, mainly by [vectorization](/questions/tagged/vectorization). I would suggest you looked into the following resources:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474808/how-does-matlabs-parfeval-function-work), for additional info on `parfeval`.
- Examples on how to use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) and benchmarks thereof: [ex1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807960/bsxfun-implementation-in-matrix-multiplication/23808285#23808285), [ex2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152504/how-can-i-calculate-dyadics-in-matlab-without-using-for-loops/27153395), [ex3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431048/how-to-randomly-permute-columns-in-3d-matrix-in-matlab/6431615#6431615).

P.S.: The 2nd part of `(i = m+1:row-m,`***`i_options.cores)`*** seems out of place...